# Rails: Best way to get the "through" in has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Suppose we have the famous scenario from the Rails guide:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :appointments
   has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :physician
   belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :appointments
   has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

What's the best way to load *the* Appointment instance given one physician and one patient? 
I've been doing `Appointment.where(physician: my_physician, patient: my_patient` but that feels very dirty. Isn't there a way that returns the one single through: record?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
my_physician.appointments.where(patient: my_patient)
```

Comment: actually I got it: I think replacing where by find_by is the cleanest solution

Comment: But `find_by_*` will only return one record, because it adds `LIMIT 1` to the SQL query! So if a physician and a patient have multiple appointments, you will only get the first one. In previous versions of Rails there was `find_all_by_*`, but it is now deprecated and tells you to use `where` instead.

Comment: [From the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by): "Model.find_by finds the first record matching some conditions."

Comment: To my understanding, the `:through` model is uniquely identified by its patient and physician foreign keys, so there can only be one per patient/physician combination. Am I wrong?

Comment: so the appointment table would look like `( (patient_id, physician_id):pk, time:datetime, ...)`. No?

Comment: There is no reason why you shouldn't be able to add multiple appointments, each for the same patient/physician combination. If you don't want that, you will have to check for it...  And, I think that mostly, that's also what you want?